# Calculate percentage if containts text in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image: table]

I have a situation like in the picture and everytime I have to manually calculate 22% of E cells and write it into H cells, I'm trying to automatically calculate 22% of E columns and have the result in each cell in H column only where match IT in Cou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple `IF()` statement should work.  In `H2` put this and drag down:

```
=IF($C2="IT",1.22*$E2,$E2+$F2)
```

Note: You're actually, from the screenshot, trying to calculate 122% it looks like, which is why I did `1.22*`.  Also, change the final `$E2+$F2` to be what you want if column C is *not* `IT`.

Edit: Actually, I'm not sure what you want to do if there's no `IT`. For row with "BOB", you're still doing `122%` of the column E number...so just adjust that last bit as necessary.

Comment: I would change `.22` to `1.22`. Based on the results in the spreadsheet, looks like the OP wants to add 22%. EDIT: Sorry, you just did that haha.